# Add stacked border color in Highchart?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

How can I add stacked border color in highchart?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can vote for that feature in Highcharts [here](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3075370-outline-border-to-stacked-column-bar).

I created simple example for you, using renderer to **add** these shapes. Note, that you should update these shapes in `chart.events.redraw` event with proper dimensions: http://jsfiddle.net/qwxj9d7o/

Comment: Super Bro.... really very useful for me... Use this how i can add flag on above bar.... if u have any idea pls share with me...

Comment: Use scatter series with custom marker (easy). Or use renderer, to render flag (harder).

Comment: In which option? With scatter series - calculate position (total sum per stack = y value) before rendering the chart and add scatter points per stack (x-value). For renderer, use the same logic as I used for rendering border (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwxj9d7o/3/ ). To add image, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image).

Comment: Hi... Its not working.. I have scroll bar also... if i scroll this borders are position fixed...

Comment: It is working, you just need to manage borders on each redraw too, for example, store borders and rects, then remove them and crete news on redraw, see: http://jsfiddle.net/qwxj9d7o/4/ - just as I said in my answer above..

Answer (score 0):

You could wait until they add the property... or you could add a dynamic event handler like this.

```
$('#bar_container').on('hover','#bar_id',function(){
    $(this).css('border','1px solid #ffff00');
}
```

That way the someone hover the bar it will highlight in yellow event when the bar was created dynamically.

Comment: So in that case just changer 'hover' for 'load'. Give it a try